# Having trouble getting UIView sizeToFit to do anything meaningful

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, resize, uibutton

When I add a subview to a `UIView`, or when I resize an existing subview, I would expect `[view sizeToFit]` and `[view sizeThatFits]` to reflect that change. However, my experience is that `sizeToFit` does nothing, and `sizeThatFits` returns the same value before and after the change.

My test project has a single view that contains a single button. Clicking the button adds another button to the view and then calls `sizeToFit` on the containing view. The bounds of the view are dumped to the console before and after adding the subview.

```
- (void) logSizes {
 NSLog(@"theView.bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(theView.bounds));
 NSLog(@"theView.sizeThatFits: %@", NSStringFromCGSize([theView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero])); 
}

- (void) buttonTouched { 
 [self logSizes];
 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 btn.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 100.0f, 400.0f, 600.0f);
 [theView addSubview:btn];
 [theView sizeToFit];
 [self performSelector:@selector(logSizes) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

And the output is:

```
2010-10-15 15:40:42.359 SizeToFit[14953:207] theView.bounds: {{0, 0}, {322, 240}}
2010-10-15 15:40:42.387 SizeToFit[14953:207] theView.sizeThatFits: {322, 240}
2010-10-15 15:40:43.389 SizeToFit[14953:207] theView.bounds: {{0, 0}, {322, 240}}
2010-10-15 15:40:43.391 SizeToFit[14953:207] theView.sizeThatFits: {322, 240}
```

I must be missing something here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The documentation is pretty clear on this. `-sizeToFit` pretty much calls `-sizeThatFits:` (probably with the view's current size as the argument), and the default implementation of `-sizeThatFits:` does almost nothing (it just returns its argument).

Some UIView subclasses override `-sizeThatFits:` to do something more useful (e.g. UILabel). If you want any other functionality (such as resizing a view to fit its subviews), you should subclass UIView and override `-sizeThatFits:`.

Comment: Thanks Ole. Should have read the docs more closely rather than looking at code snippets that relied on the overridden behavior in a particular subclass of UIView.

Comment: I'm surprised there's no answer here that shares their implementation of such an override.

Answer (score 7):

If you won't override UIView, u can just use extension.

Swift:

```
extension UIView {

    func sizeToFitCustom () {
        var size = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        for view in self.subviews {
            let frame = view.frame
            let newW = frame.origin.x + frame.width
            let newH = frame.origin.y + frame.height
            if newW > size.width {
                size.width = newW
            }
            if newH > size.height {
                size.height = newH
            }
        }
        self.frame.size = size
    }

}
```

The same code but 3 times faster:

```
extension UIView {
    final func sizeToFitCustom() {
        var w: CGFloat = 0,
            h: CGFloat = 0
        for view in subviews {
            if view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.width > w { w = view.frame.origin.x + view.frame.width }
            if view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.height > h { h = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.height }
        }
        frame.size = CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some like that using IB alone (xcode 4.5):

1. Click on the `UIView`
2. in the Size inspector drag `content hugging` to 1 (both horizontal and vertical)
3. drag `compression resistance` to 1000 (for both)
4. under the UIView's `constraints` click on `Width` and change `priority` to 250
5. Do the same for Height
6. You can use the `UIView`'s `inset` to control padding for left/right/top/bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
        self.errorMessageLabel.text = someNewMessage;

    // We don't know how long the given error message might be, so let's resize the label + containing view accordingly
    CGFloat heightBeforeResize = self.errorMessageLabel.frame.size.height;

    [self.errorMessageLabel sizeToFit];

    CGFloat differenceInHeightAfterResize = self.errorMessageLabel.frame.size.height - heightBeforeResize;

    self.errorViewHeightContstraint.constant = kErrorViewHeightConstraintConstant + differenceInHeightAfterResize;
```

This worked for me.