# Creating a UIImage from a UIImageView and a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigraphicscontext

I am using the following code from a previous answer to create a new UIImage from combining a UIImageView and a UITextView.

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[parentView addSubview:self.imagePreview];
[self.imagePreview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[parentView addSubview:self.memeTextFieldTop];
[self.memeTextFieldTop setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 20)];
[parentView sizeToFit];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([parentView bounds].size);
[[parentView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The problem seems to be that I am currently getting the following errors and I am unsure how to go about solving them.

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextGetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextConcatCTM: invalid context 0x0
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I see you did [parentView sizeToFit]; Did you make sure the frame is not CGRectZero?

Comment: thats' because of parentView frame size still remains zero. Check the frame with NSLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sizeToFit doesn't work on UIView. You have to override this method to work as you expected. See [iphone uiview - resize frame to fit subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605393/iphone-uiview-resize-frame-to-fit-subviews) and [Having trouble getting UIView sizeToFit to do anything meaningful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946665/having-trouble-getting-uiview-sizetofit-to-do-anything-meaningful)

Comment: I have managed to change it so that the uiimageview sets the size of the UIView

Answer (score 1):

The log shows you dont have a valid context for drawing

As per docs

> UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
>
> The current graphics context is nil by default. Prior to calling its
> drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack,
> making it current. If you are not using a UIView object to do your
> drawing, however, you must push a valid context onto the stack
> manually using the UIGraphicsPushContext function.

By calling UIGraphicsPushContext() with the context you've created, your other methods can access that context with UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext().

If you're calling **UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() outside of drawRect:** and **haven't set a context explicitly with UIGraphicsPushContext()**, the current graphics context is undefined—and certainly not safe to use