# Horizontally center multiple UIViews

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I want to horizontally center a number of UIViews (they happen to be circles) in the master UIView.  It will end up basically looking like the dots on the standard Page Control.

I have all the code written to create the circle UIViews I just have no idea how to arrange them horizontally and dynamically at run time.

Essentially I need some kind of horizontal container where I can do this

```
-(void)addCircle{
  [self addSubView:[CircleView init]];
}
```

And it will auto arrange however many children it has in the center.

Comment: Tried `layoutSubviews` or auto-layout constraints?

Comment: Which are you using, auto layout or autoresizing masks?

Comment: I have constraints enabled but I find them extremely counter intuitive compared to, well, ever other technology I've used lol. I was hoping someone could advise the best way to do it as I literally have no idea where to start...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I get confused with auto-layout as well from time to time but here is a way how you can do it programmatically: (I assume that you add your circle views to a `containerView` property of your view controller and you do not add any other views to it.)

1. Add these two properties to your view controller:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic) CGRect circleViewFrame;
   @property (nonatomic) CGFloat delta;
   ```
2. Initiate those properties with the desired values in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

   ```
   // the size (frame) of your circle views
   self.circleViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
   // the horizontal distance between your circle views
   self.delta = 10.0;
   ```
3. Now we add your "automatic addCircle method":

   ```
   - (void)addCircleView {
     UIView *newCircleView = [self createCircleView];
     [self.containerView addSubview:newCircleView];
     [self alignCircleViews];
   }
   ```
4. Of course we need to implement the `createCircleView` method...

   ```
   - (UIView*)createCircleView {
     // Create your circle view here - I use a simple square view as an example
     UIView *circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.circleViewFrame];
     // Set the backgroundColor to some solid color so you can see the view :)
     circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

     return circleView;
   }
   ```
5. ... and the `alignCircleViews` method:

   ```
   - (void)alignCircleViews {
     int numberOfSubviews = [self.containerView.subviews count];
     CGFloat totalWidth = (numberOfSubviews * self.circleViewFrame.size.width) + (numberOfSubviews - 1) * self.delta;
     CGFloat x = (self.containerView.frame.size.width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2);

     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSubviews; i++) {
         UIView *circleView = self.containerView.subviews[i];
         circleView.frame = CGRectMake(x,
                                 self.circleViewFrame.origin.y,
                                 self.circleViewFrame.size.width,
                                 self.circleViewFrame.size.height);
         x += self.circleViewFrame.size.width + self.delta;
     }
   }
   ```

This is the most important method which will automatically realign all your subviews each time a new circleView is added. The result will look like this:

[image: sample view controller with 3 horizontally centered subviews]
[image: sample view controller with 8 horizontally centered subviews]

Comment: Hey Mischa, I havent had chance to test this yet but looks very promising thankyou!

Comment: Glad to be of help. ;)

Comment: Good answer. I translated it to Swift so I can use it in my Swift app. The Swift code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/aCeKmdeM

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps: append circle to container view, resize container view, center align container view

```
-(void)addToContanerView:(CircleView*)circle{

    circle.rect.frame = CGrectMake(containers_end,container_y,no_change,no_change);
    [containerView addSubview:circle];
    [containerView sizeToFit];
    containerView.center = self.view.center;
}
```

Assumptions:
containers_end & containers_y you can get from CGRectMax function,
for UIView SizeToFit method check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605393/iphone-uiview-resize-frame-to-fit-subviews)

To take care of rotation use make sure your Autoresizing subviews are set for left, right bottom and top margin.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this library. I have used it on several of my projects and so far, it worked really well.

https://github.com/davamale/DMHorizontalView