# Resize UIView inside UIScrollView with AutoLayout for scrolling?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a layout as follows(Using AutoLayout,iPad):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

The `UIScrollView` has Top,Bottom,Leading,Trailing space to the superview as 0. The `UIView` also has all four similar constraints. The second `UILabel` has its height set to 0 programmatically (since more than a screenful of text is shown here). Also, these four pin constraints have also been set up from the `UIView` to `UIScrollView`.

When the XIB is loaded, this `UILabel` shows long lines of text correctly. But scrolling does not work. This is a screenshot of the running app on an iPad:

[image]

The yellow background is set for the outermost view and the grey one for the `UIView`. If you see carefully at the end of the screenshot, the `UILabel`'s text seems to overflow past the `UIView`.

I suspect that because the `UIView` cannot "capture" the size of it's subviews, the `UIScrollView` cannot calculate it's contentsize too(there's no reason for the scrollbar to work if its content view is only equal to one screen). Why is this happening even when the `UILabel` is clearly a subview of the `UIView`? If my suspicions are right, **how do I set the `UIView`'s height equal to the actual content size so that my `UILabel` is properly "contained" in it?**

(Setting the `UIView`'s height,width statically is not an option) .

NB: Tested the XIB without the `UIView` and only a single `UILabel` (with long text) inside a `UIScrollView`. Now scrolling works(since, I presume, the scroll view can calculate its content size).

NB2: I also tried the answers in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605393/iphone-uiview-resize-frame-to-fit-subviews) and [this post](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/) but my `UIView` simply wont extend beyond the dimensions of the screen. (I only care about horizontal scrolling)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AutoLayout issues are very hard to explain with text. I was having the same problem. I found the solution in this video. hope this will help you too.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI

> This video demonstrates how to create a UIScrollView which has some
>   views on the top of the screen and a view on the bottom of the screen
>   in Autolayout. UIScrollView content size is automatically adjusted to
>   the size of the screen or to the size of the content in such way that
>   on smaller devices scrolling is active and on larger devices scrolling
>   is not active because it is not needed. UIButton below UITextFields
>   always stays on the bottom of the screen and everything works on all
>   iPhone resolutions (iPhone 4 / 5 / 6 / 6 Plus).

Comment: That was unbelievably awesome! The trick was to have another `UIView` **outside** the `UIScrollView` and then to set "Equal heights and widths" constraints from the *inner* `UIView` to the **outer** `UIView`. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Saved my day! 
..and for anyone interested in that, I set "Equal widths" and "Equal heights" from the inner UIView to the scrollView itself.

Comment: Best answer , I have come across till now.