# Autoresizing UIView inside UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I have few fields and UIView inside the UIScrollView (Fields on top and UIView at the bottom. UIScrollview size is larger than the screen size).

What i am thinking!

UIView should be autoresize according to its super view (UIScrollView) but it is resizing according to UIViewController view..

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278185/resize-uiview-inside-uiscrollview-with-autolayout-for-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
```

this will animate all layers from the current state.